# Colour Bleeding

Tags: vertex-colors

I have made this circle for an eye. I would like the white to fill the selected faces only, but for some reason it is going way beyond. Any ideas what I could do? Many thanks!

[image: White bleeding]

Comment: It doesn't look like these are vertex colors painted on the mesh. Are you sure you ask about [vertex painting](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/painting_sculpting/painting/vertex_paint/introduction.html) but not about [materials](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/render/blender_render/materials/introduction.html) or something else ?

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant materials... However, I have now made some proper eyes with globes now so the problem is somewhat solved in that sense... Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If the problem is solved you could add the exact steps as an answer to your own question to show that you found solution. It's a good idea to include some screenshots along with description in your answer detailing what were the steps you made.

Comment: What I mean is that I made my eyes differently so I did not actually solve the issue, I just used spheres and put them in the eye sockets like so: (http://i.imgur.com/aFa3FAu.png)